# How to use multiple threads inside requestAnimationFrame that calls a Web Assembly function?

Tags: javascript, c++, multithreading, webassembly

I'm developing a particle system that has a huge (possibly over 1 million) number of particles.
To calculate their positions each frame, I'm using a wasm function to speed up the calculation.

It looks like this:

Javascript:

```js
function animate() {
  Module.ccall('calculatePositions', ...);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

C++:

```cpp
// particles array is stored in C++
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE int* calculatePositions(...) {
  for (int i = 0; i < particlesNumber; i++) {
    calculatePosition(particles[i]);
  );
  
  return updatedPositionsArray; // also stored in C++, but updated when I call calculate positions
}
```

It works fine, but the CPU struggles, when the number of particles is over 1 million.
Now, what I thought I could do is calculate positions on 2 threads to speed up the process:

```cpp
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE int* calculatePositions(...) {
  std::thread threadOne (calculatePositionsFromTo, 0, particlesNumber/2);
  calculatePositionsFromTo(particlesNumber/2, particlesNumber);

  threadOne.join();

  return updatedPositionsArray;
}
```

However, when I do the `join()` that the tab hangs forever.
I assume the reason is somehow related to this: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/pthreads.html#special-considerations

Specifically,

> When pthread_create() is called, if we need to create a new Web Worker, then that requires returning the main event loop. That is, you cannot call pthread_create and then keep running code synchronously that expects the worker to start running - it will only run after you return to the event loop. This is a violation of POSIX behavior and will break common code which creates a thread and immediately joins it or otherwise synchronously waits to observe an effect such as a memory write.

However, as a JavaScript developer, I have never worked with multithreading before and don't understand how to overcome this limitation or whether it's even possible. Is there any other way to utilise threads to speed up the calculation process? Also, could you please explain specifically why it hangs?

Answer (score 1):

Make your query async.

Like, call into C++ wasm and ask for it to calculate what you want, and call back to tell you it is ready later.

You could use asynctify or something to get that working, but as a javascript programmer you probably should just make a JS webworker and have that synchronously call into your C++ wasm.

Another option would be to set up a pool of wasm threads earlier, in startup code, then use them here.  I think emscripten even has a way to do that automatically for you (I forget how), or you could do it in C++ and write a thread pool.

(Note: I have done nothing but toy programs in wasm at this point; so take the above with a grain of salt.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I don't think that calculating physics asynchronously would work. I expected that every time I would spawn a new thread it would calculate and synchronously return the results so I can use them right away in my animation function.

Comment: @peancored I didn't say spawn a new thread each time.  That isn't required for async, at least in C++.